# Why does jQuery's DatePicker Impl Not Work In Safari?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using Play's form generator for a date I get a functional datepicker in Chrome:

[image]

But in Safari it does not work at all:

[image]

I tried different versions of jQuery to see if that would make a difference.  I verified JS is enabled in Safari.

Can't find any currently open tickets on this issue.

Any ideas?

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/utvfLfgr/

And the required code...

```
<form action="/" method="POST" >

<dl class=" " id="datepicker_field">
    <dt><label for="datepicker">Date Picker</label></dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="date" id="datepicker" name="Date Picker" value="" />
    </dd>

</dl>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pics but I'd rather prefer a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)..

Comment: What does this has to do with the Play Framework? Such framework doesn't provide (at least not out of the box) UI components. Also some code would be helpful. Sounds like CSS/JS issue.

Comment: Anton, play does provide ui components.  Look at the form helpers.  Urbz, I will try to get a fiddle up.

Answer (score 2):

Oops... I assumed jQuery was providing the date picker.

It is a native browser feature, that most have not yet implemented.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Check out my link, its not exactly working. Its not something jquery can fix, but I did use its datepicker as an alternative.